# how to insert another level of drill down into report?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I currently have a working drill down report.

I would like to add another level of drill down, and I do not know how to do it.

I have this right now:

[image]

But the last row that shows `<<Expr>>` needs to be included under the row above it.

**How can I include an extra level of drill down?**

I did what @eestein recommended, and here's the result:

[image]

as you can see the bottom row has not been associated with the one above it!

Comment: You need to put that at the same level? If yes, just right click and add row inside group, otherwise just create the upper `<<Expr>>` as an outer group of the lower `<<Expr>>`. If that's not it, try to specify what you need.

Comment: @eestein thank you very much! i did the add row inside group and here's what i am getting: http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/9546/201304121252.png

Comment: Per your comment you want to associate with the row above? What do you mean by that? If you want both data on the same row, just press enter inside the cell and add the info. I honestly didn't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @eestein i apologize for not being clear. in my case, the last row is just 1 column. that column is just the last column of the row above it. another words, i want to display the last field of a row, right underneath it, but i want that specific row to be exandeable/retractable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, from you last comment I think I understood what you mean.
To accomplish that you will need to create an element in the row above a `+` sign, for instance, and then bind that to the hidden property of your row below.

1. Create an element with a `+` sign
2. Press F4 on the row you want to expand/retract
3. Roll all the way to the end until you see the visibility group
4. On `ToggleItem` select the name of the item with a `+` sign
5. Set your `Hidden` to true

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220405(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want two levels of 'detail' but that may be in a group as well.  SSRS has an option when you click in a cell you can choose 'Insert Row' that expands to 'Inside Group ...' or 'Outside Group ...'.  If you want a parallel level of detail continued with a prior row just choose 'Inside Group' and it should continue information only level to that level of either 'Detail' row, 'Parent Group1', 'Parent Group2' etc...